# Disable only Horizontal Scroll in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, horizontal-scrolling

I am Using a third party Library [richeditor-android](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android).

The Library is Great in it self and uses android web-view to provide text rich features. When you are done editing a text you can take it as a string and show it in the same Rich Editor's web-view after using

`setInputEnabled(false)`

But the problem is that web-view doesn't wrap text and instead enables horizontal scroll view for words longer than the screen.(The result is same with a normal web-view) I want the web-view to show the text in a similar pattern that it used to show it when I was editing the text.

I have Used everything mentioned in various answers available on stack overflow but no success yet. The main Problem is I want to disable only horizontal scroll while allow user to scroll vertically.

I have inserted images for example.

Image when I am entering the text.

[image]

Image when I am showing the Text.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code to remove the horizontal scroll using CSS.

Make a .css file in your assets folder, and paste the below code in that file.

```
.wrap {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

After that in your Activity put the below code.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=\"justify.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body><div class=\"wrap\"> ");  //Justify.css is the name of the file in your assets folder
            sb.append("YOUR TEXT");
            sb.append("</div></body></HTML>");
            web_view.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```